# Problema con memoria en R

Tags: r

Tengo un problema al ejecutar volúmenes de datos de tamaño considerable en R
Al ejecutar un modelo de knn

```
library(kknn) 
modelo<-train.kknn(nac_ext~., data= taprendizaje, kmax = 3) 
modelo
```

obtengo este error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 216.1 Gb

Alguien me puede dar una pista de como solucionar este problema?

Comment: Por favor adjunta el código de lo que estás intentando. ¿De casualidad estás generando una matriz de distancias?

Comment: Gracias Patricio el código es el siguiente: library(kknn)
modelo<-train.kknn(nac_ext~., data= taprendizaje, kmax = 3)
modelo

Comment: @ROBERTOESPINOZA por favor agrega esa información en la pregunta

Comment: Estoy realizando la ejecuci[on de modelos predictivos en R, tratando de predecir con varios modelos si la siguiente cancion a sonar en radio es extranjera o nacional. EL motivo es que al correr el modelo KNN este me manda como error library(kknn) modelo<-train.kknn(nac_ext~., data= taprendizaje, kmax = 3) quiro saber como corregir ya que con naive bayes no tengo este problema

Comment: ¿Qué dimensión tiene `taprendizaje`? copia la salida de `dim(taprendizaje)`